# Convert JSON string to JSON object using R

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

How to convert that to a json object in  R package jsonlite?

the problem is I want to use an R function that expects a JSON object as argument. And I find myself doing `toJSON(fromJSON(jsonStr))` every time I want to pass a JSON string just to change it's class to json.

```
jsonStr <- '{"radius": 200, "color": "blue"}'

r2d3(data = as_d3_data(toJSON(fromJSON(jsonStr))),script = 'whatever.js')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I find myself doing `toJSON(fromJSON(jsonStr))` every time I want to pass a JSON string just to change it's class to json.

The idiomatic way to change the class of an object is:

```
class(jsonStr) <- "json"
```

To make sure the string is valid, might want to use `jsonlite::validate(jsonStr)` after assigning the class.(Thanks to @SybolixAU for pointing this out.)

Comment: (I couldn't find a dupe so am making my comment into an answer. Happy to delete it if a good dupe target is found)

Comment: might want to use `jsonlite::validate(jsonStr)` to validate it after assigning the class